# Using GUI for existing J2ME application

Tags: java, user-interface, java-me

I am a newbie to developing GUI for J2ME applications.

I have developed one using Netbeans IDE with basic UI,but I would like to develop the UI of my application for making it more stylish for the smart phones.

Please suggest the best GUI tool that could be used to develop on an existing j2me app.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for an IDE? You want to make your phone UI look better?

Comment: I basically want to know whether tools like LWUIT and J2ME polish (which are used for developing the GUI for J2ME apps)  can be used for existing j2me apps,like just inserting few lines of codes to the existing one instead of rewriting the complete code.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest against a GUI tool to do this.  Instead put the UI together by hand.  It will provide much better flexibility and will allow you to have code that is easily read and modified.

Comment: But wouldn't putting up the UI by hand be too time consuming.I just want to add few basic transition effects and simple background for my app.The main objective is to achieve the above by adding few lines of codes to the existing ones.I have heard about LWUIT and J2ME Polish for this purpose but I wanted to know if any of the above be used for developing the GUI for an existing application.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A GUI Builder can get your 80% of the way really quick but makes the last 20% really hard.   Doing it by hand takes a little longer at first, but long term allows you to build things faster.

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot for the info,but I have time constraints that makes me ask you if it is possible for some GUI Builder to be used by an existing application by just inserting few codes to the existing codes,something like CSS for web.Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can make some look and feel changes to an application. That is similar to CSS.  However, not everything can be done through look and feel changes.